# Setting dynamic array key in while loop php

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, while-loop

I have this code

```
$query = "SELECT `subscriberid`,`data` FROM `****table_name*****`"
    . "WHERE `subscriberid` IN (123,456,789,101)";
$result = $cxn->query($query);
$Points = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $Points[$row['subscriberid']] = $row['data'];
}
```

I want the keys for $Points to be the subscriberid, but when I print out $Points I keep getting default keys 0-3 and I can't see any reason for this to be happening.

Comment: Are you sure `$Points` isn't declared somewhere else? ie; it's a unique variable? Also, you could try an alias on the field: `"SELECT subscriberid AS sid, data FROM...` then use `$row['sid']`

Comment: Can you make a `var_dump($Points)` please, and a `var_dump($row)` in between the while loop please.

Comment: Also, you should only iterate if there was a result; wrap your `while...` loop in `if ($result = $cxn->query($query)) {` and `}` instead of just `$result = $cxn->query($query);`

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @Jongosi's Comment, about the `if ($result = $cxn->query($query))` part.

Your query is currently as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT `subscriberid`,`data` FROM `****table_name*****`"
    . "WHERE `subscriberid` IN (123,456,789,101)";
```

If you only edited `****table_name*****`, you are missing a space ( between `*` and `WHERE`).

Your result will be nothing or an error.

```
$query = "SELECT `subscriberid`,`data` FROM `****table_name*****`"
    . " WHERE `subscriberid` IN (123,456,789,101)";
```

Comment: Well I realized after much testing that I have been writing every thing properly. I printed everything out in a document that resides in the same folder as the class running this method. I found my issue happens when I am using nusoap as a web-service to run those methods across two different servers. I'm thinking nusoap is somehow converting my arrays, because my keys are being reinterpreted and in a totally wrong way. This is still a mystery.